# Is there anyway to add few URL's as false findings in ZAP for preventing them not to encounter in new scans

Tags: owasp

There are few issues reporting by the ZAP tool which are included in our code somewhere deep. I want these URL's to be excluded for the later scans.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude those URLs from your scan, or use Alert Filters to flag them as false positives (even if they are not really;)

More details on https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/how-do-i-handle-a-false-positive/